# Talk Back accessibility, requesting focus on a TextView

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

We have a requirment for accessibility that when a given activity opens and the user has TalkBack accessibility on, the client wants the Talk Back to not just read the activity name, but also the text of our `welcomeText` TextView.  That text view is dynamic in that it will say "Welcome, "

I tried doing this in the activity onCreate() by saying:

```
welcomeText =(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.authenticatedNoWishlistWelcomeText);

welcomeText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
welcomeText.requestFocus();
```

but this is not working.. can anyone tell me how i can get Talk Back to read a given TextView upon launch without the user interaction?

Answer (score 7):

The important thing to realize here, is that `Focus` and `Accessibility Focus` are not the same thing.

You are looking for the following:

```
welcomeText.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

Be careful about when you do this.  Doing this in onCreate is probably a bad idea, as then it will only happen when the application activity is loaded.  What you probably want is for it to happen each time it is resumed.  Also, the AT (TalkBack) creates its connection to the Activity at some point in this lifecycle, and so you want to be sure you don't have a race condition.  TalkBack must connect to your activity before you post your Accessibility Event.

Though note, that this may be a bad requirement.  WCag 3.2.1 and 3.2.3 clearly state that navigation should be consistent and predictable, and part of this is avoiding unexpected shifts of focus.  This could be considered a violation of these guidelines, and actually less accessible than not doing so.

Comment: Can this Accessibility Focus be requested within the layout XML? It could be nice to have sort of an android:firstViewToReadOutLoud attribute.

Comment: If you are using bindings - it can be done via an bindingAdapter